# Keras: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a neural network using Keras but am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 25168 but received input with shape (None, 34783)
```

I defined the model to be:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_dim = len(X), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

In this, `X` is the result of using scikit-learn it's `CountVectorizer()` (after it is trained) as follows:

```
X = count_vectorizer.transform(X).todense()
```

Is there any method to fix this? Looking around I found that I might need to reshape the data, however I have no idea how and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using as `input_dim` the sample dimensionality: `len(X)` (the same as `X.shape[0]`) which is wrong.

Keras expects as input  the number of dimensions of the features which, in your case of 2D input, is `X.shape[-1]`